# Build Failed after running react-native run-android --variant=release

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-ios

Execution failed for task `':app:installRelease'`.

```
com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException:
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package
couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.example: Package
/data/app/com.example/base.apk code is missing
```

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed by deleting the app release apk in `Example/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk`
and re-building

Comment: You are welcome @AliAkbarAzizi